# Little Boxes on the Hillside

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, graphical-output

There's a satirical song called [*Little Boxes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Boxes), originally by Malvina Reynolds, about suburban sprawl that has lyrics as follows:

> Little boxes on the hillside,
>   Little boxes made of ticky-tacky,
>   Little boxes on the hillside,
>   Little boxes all the same.
>   There's a green one and a pink one
>   And a blue one and a yellow one,
>   And they're all made out of ticky-tacky
>   And they all look just the same.

Your job here is, given an integer input `n>1` that represents the size of the house, output the four "little boxes" using the following colors (in 0xRRGGBB notation):

```
Green -- 0x00FF00
Pink --- 0xFF00FF (technically magenta)
Blue --- 0x0000FF
Yellow - 0xFFFF00
```

*If your particular console doesn't have these exact colors, you may use the closest available (e.g., ANSI escape codes).*

The houses are constructed with `n` `_` representing the floor and roofline. They are surrounded by `n/2` (round-up) `|` characters representing the walls. The roofs are always `2` high and are two `/` on the left edge, two `\` on the right edge, and `n-2` `-` representing the roof peak. As the houses get larger, the comparative size of the roof gets smaller; this is intended.

Here's a house of size `2`:

```
 /\
/__\
|__|
```

Here's size `3`:

```
 /-\
/___\
|   |
|___|
```

Here's size `7`:

```
 /-----\
/_______\
|       |
|       |
|       |
|_______|
```

Thus given an input of `7`, output four houses of size `7` as described above, with the first one in green, the second in pink (magenta), the third in blue, and the fourth in yellow. *Output of the colors in that order is important.*

Example picture of size `3`:

[image]

#### Rules

- The houses can be horizontal or vertical so long as there is a clear separation between them.
- Leading/trailing newlines or other whitespace are optional, provided that the houses line up appropriately.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- Output can be to the console, saved as an image, etc.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>123</s> <s>121</s> <s>119</s> <s>111</s> <s>109</s> 108 bytes

- Saved two bytes thanks to [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing); using the actual unprintable ASCII character instead of escaping it (`\33`)
- Could (and did) save a byte by writing an entire program using `input()` instead of defining a function
- Saved seven bytes thanks to [ElPedro](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56555/elpedro); using the fact that `str(90+n)` with `0<=n<=9` is `"9%s"%n`
- Saved <s>two</s> three bytes by using string formatting rather than string concatenation

```python
N=input()
for(n)in"2543":Z="_"*N;print"[9%sm /"%n+~-~-N*"-"+"\ \n/%s\\\n"%Z+~-N/2*("|%s|\n"%" "*N)+"|%s|"%Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/3882M6@gtERDkystv0gjTzMzT8nI1MRYySrKVileScvPuqAoM69ESTraUrU4V0FfSTVPu063TtdPS0lXSVspRiEmT1@1OCYmJk9JNQoo46dvpKWhVKNaXAMSUVIAmqCpDeYD5f//NwIA)

Uses [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) for coloring the houses.

Comment: [119 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcqxCsIwFEbhWV/B5fJPSW5C5aqDfYCOeQEDdtBiB29L6SIEXz2GOp6PM3/W16RSyuM5UGeibfe7YVpIaVQSf/Fnf2rnZdQVhxu4V74ee8abGrCJQaxDACNR0iq4w8VaKSn4G2IjziBXp81zZcsb/MeM0hmx5Qc)

Comment: 112 by looping "2543" and using string formatting - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TcFNw0/TioszLb9II08zM0/JyNTEWMmqoCgzr0RJOtpStThXQV9JNU9bw0/XSFNLSVdJWylGISZPH0jHK2n5AXkxMXlK2nW6fvpGWhpKNUBxBbB4DVBYUxssAFFYo/TfTcNI8z8A "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @ElPedro Thanks. Did not occur to me that `90` and `2,5,4,3` summed up is effectively concatenation.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), Chrome / Firefox, <s>156</s> <s>148</s> <s>151</s> 150 bytes

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to @Shaggy*
*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Neil*

```js
n=>['0f0','f0f','00f','ff0'].map(c=>console.log(`%c /${'-'[r='repeat'](n-2)}\\
/${s='_'[r](n)}\\
${(`|${' '[r](n)}|
`)[r](~-n/2)}|${s}|`,'color:#'+c))
```

#### Demo

Make sure to open the console of your browser to get the colored output.

```js
let f =

n=>['0f0','f0f','00f','ff0'].map(c=>console.log(`%c /${'-'[r='repeat'](n-2)}\\
/${s='_'[r](n)}\\
${(`|${' '[r](n)}|
`)[r](~-n/2)}|${s}|`,'color:#'+c))

f(3)
```

Comment: Works fine for me as a Snippet, with my browser's console open. Save 8 bytes by using the 3 digit hex codes: https://tio.run/##NYvRCsIgGEbv9xSDFr/SXNJl4F5kGymmUZgOHd1se3b7E7o5fJzD91IflXR8zgvz4W5y9qIfgFsOLVhukbzQopm6t5qJFr0OPgVnOhceRB51fW5WYDBEAdHMRi0wEc8udB/HClMScMOIrphmJXLDQ/13WyVpmb8LlrRvsgUdXIjXA5w0pTl/AQ

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Are the leading `0`s necessary?

Comment: @JonathanFrech Yes. Without the leading zeros, that would not be valid `#RGB` CSS color codes.

Comment: I think the height is wrong on the wider houses.

Comment: @Neil I should have read the spec more carefully. Fixed.

Comment: `~-n/2` instead of `n/2-.5`?

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>79</s> <s>76</s> <s>74</s> <s>73</s> 72 bytes

```
3#²¤r1'f ò3 w £Ol"%c /{ç- ¤}\\
/{ç'_}\\
{/2-½ ç"|{ç}|
"}|{ç'_}|"Xi`¬l:#
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=MyOypHIxJ2Yg8jMgdyCjT2wiJWMgL3vnLSCkfVxcCi975ydffVxcCnsvMi29IOcifHvnfXwKIn18e+cnX318IlhpYKxsjjoj&input=Mg==) (Open your browser's console before hitting "Run").

<sup>Thanks to ETH for helping me to test this last night while I was working it up on my phone.</sup>

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`

```
3#²¤r1'f ò3 w
```

First we build an array of 3-digit hex colours to map over. The charcode of `²` is 178 so `3#²` gives us 3178. We convert that to a base-2 string with `¤` and then replace all occurrences of `1` with `f`. `ò3` splits the string into an array of strings of length 3 and `w` reverses that array.
<sub>(I need to figure out a way to shorten that, somehow.)</sub>

```
£Ol
```

We map over the array using `£` - with `X` being the current element - and `Ol` logs to console. We'll be passing 2 strings to that, one containing the house and one containing the CSS.

```
Xi`¬l:#
```

The second string is constructed using `i` to prepend `X` with the compressed string `color:#`.

```
"%c /{ç- ¤}\\
```

The `%c` tells the console to use the second string as CSS. The top line of the house is built by repeating (`ç`) the `-` character `U` times and then slicing that from the second element (0-indexed) with `¤`. The braces act as a shortcut, of sorts, for string concatenation.

```
/{ç'_}\\
```

The second line is built in a similar way, this time repeating the `_` character `U` times.

```
{/2-½ çRi|²iUç 1}
```

The body of the house is built by first repeating the `|` character twice with `²` and then inserting a space repeated `U` times into that string at index 1. The resulting string is then prepended to a newline (`R`) and that string is repeated `U/2-0.5` times.

```
|{ç'_}|"
```

Finally, the last line is built in the same way as the second.

Comment: Coolest Japt answer.

Comment: You only say that 'cause Japt shouldn't be able to do this, @Razetime! :D

Comment: Well, that's the point, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

## Excel VBA, 243 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from `A1` and outputs to the range `A2:A5`

```vba
[C1]=vbLf:For i=1To 4:Cells(i+1,1)=[" /"&Rept("-",A1-2)&"\"&C1&"/"&Rept("_",A1)&"\"&C1&Rept("|"&Rept(" ",A1)&"|"&C1,A1/2)&"|"&Rept("_",A1)&"|"]:Cells(i+1,1).Font.Color=Array(32768,&HFF00FF,rgbBlue,65535)(i-1):Next:Cells.Font.Name="Courier New"
```

#### Output

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 120 bytes

```python
n=input()
for i in'2543':s='_'*n;print'[1;3'+i+('m /'+'-'*(n-2)+'\ \n/%s\\\n'%s+(-~n/2-1)*('|'+' '*n+'|\n')+'|%s|\n'%s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcyxCsMgFEbhva/QxUV@9SIS0ywNeZIK3Urv0BuJdihIX91K5/Nx8qc@d4m9y8aS39XY02M/FCsWxOUy41o23OFkzQdLxfk2rTOIyeClAggezoiPlpBUkqBLSkmgCxn/lRD9ZJ1BG1CNCaGNOGzTpf2Z7X35AQ) (shows escape chars instead of actual colors, tested on local terminal)

Comment: I think your houses are too high for inputs like `n=2`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech yep I'll fix...wrong ceiling approach apparently EDIT: fixed

Comment: The question says to `use the closest available`, though you seem to use the normal colors instead of the bright colors. The bright colors -- I think -- would, however, be closer to the desired colors.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Hmm, yours seems to be using the normal colors too, but yeah the bright ones are closer.

Comment: Looks like you already used the idea that I suggested to @JonathanFrech. Sorry, I didn't steal your idea. I had not seen your answer. +1 for thinking like me.

Comment: @ElPedro Anyways his has turned out better than mine :p

Answer (score 1):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 220 bytes

An anonymous function that takes input as an integer, `n` and outputs 4 colored homes to the terminal.

The lack of a dedicated string repeating or replacement function in yabsic really hurts this response.

```vb
Clear Screen
Input""n
b$="__"
c$="|  "
For i=1To n-2
a$=a$+"-"
b$=b$+"_"
c$=c$+" "
Next
c$=c$+"|\n"
For i=1To n-4
d$=d$+c$
Next
For i=0To 3
?Color(Mid$("gremagbluyel",1+3*i,3))" /"+a$+"\\\n/"+b$+"\\\n"+d$+"|"+b$+"|"
Next
```

This version requires graphics mode and thus does not work on TIO.

#### Output

The input value for the below is `n=7`.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 115 bytes

```
INPUT N
H.H 6H 4H 2DEF H C
COLOR C+5?" /";"-"*(N-2);"\
?"/";"_"*N;"\
FOR I=3TO N?"|";" "*N;"|
NEXT?"|";"_"*N;"|
END
```

Another one which is also 115 bytes:

```
INPUT N
FOR J=0TO 3COLOR!!J*8-J*2+5?" /";"-"*(N-2);"\
?"/";"_"*N;"\
FOR I=3TO N?"|";" "*N;"|
NEXT?"|";"_"*N;"|
END
```

The colors codes I need (in 4-bit RGBI) are 5, 11, 9, 7. This is generated using `!!J*8-J*2+5` If J is not 0, this is `13-J*2` (giving 11,9,7), and if it is, the result is just 5.