# Creating a 16x16(NxN) grid

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

This is my first question in `Code golf` I found it in stack-overflow (originally in JavaScript however all languages are acceptable):

*Render on screen NxN (where N in range 1-16) grid where each cell have black boundary and red number inside - cells are numerated in hex starting from left-upper corner to bottom-right. Example output (for N=16) shows how result should looks like (font can be different than in picture):*

[image]

The image in text uri form (which works on major browsers) in output is also acceptable - a as example blow:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
```

This is my (not optimised) attempt to this task

```js
document.write('<style>.row { display: flex; font-size: 9.5px; text-align: center; color: red } .cell { width: 10px; height: 10px; margin: 1px; border: 1px solid black;}</style><div id="container"></div>')

let n=10, s='';

for(let i=0; i<n; i++) {
  s+= '<div class="row">'
  for(let j=0; j<n; j++) s+= `<div class="cell"> ${(i*n+j).toString(16)} </div>`;
  s+= '</div>'
}

container.innerHTML = s;
```

but I wonder how small code can produce similar effect?

Comment: Was starting to work on a brainfuck solution until I realised it can't output text in red :'(

Comment: @Therandomguy I'm pretty sure you can use [weird ANSI escape magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (but I might be wrong)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/103403/52210)

Comment: @Kamil to be fair, that allows you to either golf a font and a image encoder or compress 16 uncompressible different strings in a language that presumably cannot output colored text; doesn't really sound better than weird ANSI escape magic.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski if "NxN (where N in range 1-16)" is no longer a requirement it should be removed from the spec, although I don't know why you're allowing a uri now.

Comment: Are we allowed to have all the blocks align without spaces in between them (see my current PowerShell screenshot)? If not I'll delete and fix it (later when I have some more time).

Comment: Why are some of your comments deleted now?.. An few hours ago you said input wasn't required, and @JonathanAllan asked to remove it from the challenge description as response. And now those comments are removed without a change to the challenge description.. So, do we take an input or not? And please edit the challenge description accordingly..

Comment: What is the motivation behind requiring that the output be colored? That seems like an arbitrary expectation that prevents many different golfing environments from competing. Is that really an integral part of the challenge?

Comment: I've VTCed this as unclear as, other than the issue of whether or not we should take input, there are a lot of things not covered by the spec including, but not limited to, border size, margins, padding and justification of text.

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as p;o='center';[p.subplot(16,16,1+x,yticks=[],xticks=[]).text(0.5,0.5,hex(x)[2:],color='r',va=o,ha=o) for x in range(256)]`

question was closed but I wanted to do a python+matplotlib one anyway - 148 characters (requires matplotlib)

Comment: @HughNolan thank you for your answer - can you provide link where I can execute code online or at least some screenshot with result.

Comment: The question description with desired example (N=16) output image, JS snippet and tag `graphical-output` provide all information about task (including margin, paddings, colors etc., parameter N which is in range 1-16 e.g. in JS snippet is N=10 in screenshot is N=16... - I never say that N is fixed - question was clear). So what next - how I should change the question?

Comment: @Kamil Kiełczewski, it would be nice to edit the question and answer some of the asked questions so it can be re-opened and everyone can post their answers again.

Comment: Question was updated - everything should be clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could go smaller, but here's a quick one:

```js
let n=10;container.innerHTML=(d='<div class="')+'grd" style="width:'+n*14+'px">'+[...Array(n*n)].reduce((a,b,i)=>a+d+'cell">'+i.toString(16)+(e='</div>'),'')+e;
```

```css
.grd { display: inline-block; font-size: 9.5px; text-align: center; color: red;}
.cell { display:inline-block; width: 10px; height: 10px; margin: 1px; border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to codegolf ! I invite you to put your code on [tio.run](http://tio.run) and export it here. The website has a special export for StackExchange and will show your score on your answer.

Comment: @Therandomguy, would the numbers stay red when run on TIO?

Comment: @manatwork you actually got a point here ...

Comment: I believe this needs to be changed to take the `n` as input since the spec states, "NxN (where N in range 1-16)".

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 131 bytes

```
n: -1 view collect[loop 16[keep 'across
loop 16[keep compose[field 20x20 font-color red(to""to-hex/size n: n + 1 2)]]keep 'return]]
```

[image]

### If the leading zeroes need to be discarded:

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 154 bytes

```
n: -1 view collect[loop 16[keep 'across
loop 16[s: to""to-hex/size n: n + 1 2 parse s[remove"0"]keep
compose[field 20x20 font-color red(s)]]keep 'return]]
```

[image]

Note: The first screenshot is taken on my Win 10 PC, the second one - on my Win 8.1 laptop, hence the difference.

Comment: It is actually mostly red, yeah...

Comment: The first line shouldn't include leading `0`s.

Comment: @Shaggy Ok, I'll fix it tomorrow.

Comment: On second thought, it might be worth asking whether they *are* allowed first.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/powershell/powershell), 319 bytes

```
-1..15|%{If($_-lt0){$s="┌──";0..14|%{$s=$s+"┬──"};Write-Host "$s┐";}Else{$i=$_;0..15|%{Write-Host "│"-NoNewline;Write-Host ("{0:X2}"-f($i*16+$_))-f 12 -NoNewline;};Write-Host "│";$s=("├","└")[$_-eq15]+"──";0..14|%{$s=$s+(("┼","┴")[$i-eq15]+"──")};Write-Host("$s┤","$s┘")[$_-eq15]}}
```

Screenshot of the output:

[image]

Only my second PowerShell answer, so can definitely be golfed substantially.. Also, is it possible to create and use an Alias for the `Write-Host`?

**Explanation:**

*TODO: Will add one later.*

The `X2` could be `x2` to format the hexadecimal as lowercase letters.

Comment: @LuisMendo Fixed.. Can definitely be golfed some more though.. It's only my second PowerShell answer ever, so I'm not too sure what I'm doing. ;) EDIT: Hmm, comparing it to the challenge screenshot, I might need spaces between blocks.. >.>

Comment: how N could be parameterized?

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul OP said it was always 16 in the comments and as you can see at JonathanAllan's response, he asked to delete it from the challenge in that case, but now OP deleted his comments.. :S I honestly don't know anymore what the challenge is asking, since it keeps changing in the comments, without any substantial edits to the description.. >.> Three hours ago OP stated there wasn't any input required; now it sounds like there is an input required.. I'm gonna close as unclear until OP clarified AND edited the challenge description.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>51</s> 49 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Wrong tool for the job, but I got it working eventually with a little help from [my solution to *Little Boxes on the Hillside*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143481/58974). The spec doesn't include any details on margins, padding & border width so this won't look *exactly* like the reference image.

```
G²ÇsG ici%Ãú òG
£OlX¬,$...$¡`Þ:so¦d #000;¬l:d
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=R7LHc0cgaWNpJcP6IPJHCqNPbFisLCQuLi4koWDel4A6c2%2bmZCAjMDAwO6xsjjqcZA) (Open your browser's console)

If input *is* required then [this should work for <s>50</s> 48 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ssdzRyBpY2klw/og8lUKo09sWKwsJC4uLiShYN6XgDpzb6ZkICMwMDA7rGyOOpxk&input=MTY).

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 157 bytes

```php
<?php for(;$i++<$n=$_GET[n];)for(print'<p>';$$i++<$n;)echo'<x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">'.dechex($x++).'</x> ';
```

This should be run as a webpage, not from CLI. Pass input as a URL query string named `n`. For example: `grid.php?n=16`

**Sample output for `n=8`:**

```html
<p><x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">0</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">1</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">2</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">3</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">4</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">5</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">6</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">7</x> <p><x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">8</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">9</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">a</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">b</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">c</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">d</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">e</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">f</x> <p><x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">10</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">11</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">12</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">13</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">14</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">15</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">16</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">17</x> <p><x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">18</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">19</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">1a</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">1b</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">1c</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">1d</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">1e</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">1f</x> <p><x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">20</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">21</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">22</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">23</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">24</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">25</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">26</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">27</x> <p><x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">28</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">29</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">2a</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">2b</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">2c</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">2d</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">2e</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">2f</x> <p><x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">30</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">31</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">32</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">33</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">34</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">35</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">36</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">37</x> <p><x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">38</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">39</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">3a</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">3b</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">3c</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">3d</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">3e</x> <x style="color:red;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:25px">3f</x>
```

TIO link to get raw outputs (you have to save them as HTML to see the result): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzRCoIwFEB/ZdhgycgsCGJ36lP0A72FRLrFRmO7TKH59Wbk6zmHgwZn2aBBQh/Xy@3OPGtJRc5AmnoVrxC3QC3nkvrqX/kW8h/GaP3IJNYM6FpArnsTmExkGCenq6wPLkQRtYIuRKWjOODigrOKbMqyBGUHdM9JWO@s17vOhf4NH6tGI44nTFnNCrUsddrSxHleMLlPNWEwz18)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (web browser console), 160 bytes

I think a JavaScript golfer should be able to golf this idea a lot more (I'm not one!).

```js
function(n){for(x=i=0;i++<n;console.log(...a))for(j=0,a=[''];j++<n;a.push('float:left;border:1px solid #000;color:red'))a[0]+='%c'+(x++).toString(16).padEnd(2)}
```

A **155 bytes** version, but it prints some noises on top and right of the grid:

```js
function(n,a=[]){for(x=0;x<n*n;a.push('float:left;border:1px solid #000;color:red'),a[0]+='%c'+(x++).toString(16).padEnd(2))x%n?0:console.log(...a,a=[''])}
```

This only works in modern browsers console.

Sample usage in console: `f=...code above...;` and then `f(16);`

Or open your browser's console and then click on **Run code snippet** button.

```js
f=function(n){for(x=i=0;i++<n;console.log(...a))for(j=0,a=[''];j++<n;a.push('float:left;border:1px solid #000;color:red'))a[0]+='%c'+(x++).toString(16).padEnd(2)};
f(16);
```

#### Explanation:

In a modern browser console, you can use this format to apply CSS to your values printed in the console:

```js
console.log('%c Value', 'color: red; font-size: 10px;');
```

For every `%c` you have to add a new argument with your styles and those styles will be applied until the next `%c`. So to style and print two values in same line, we can use something like this:

```js
console.log('%c Value %c Value2', 'color: red; font-size: 10px;', 'font-weight: bold;');
```

In the function above, I'm collecting arguments for each row in an array called `a` and each row gets a single `console.log` for itself.

Comment: It _almost_ work in Opera, the 1st line is displayed shorter than the other ones.

Comment: @Therandomguy golfed more and this one should work in any modern browser's console.

Comment: I don't think you need the `float`, do you?

Comment: @Shaggy without `float` I lose the top border for each cell. OP says ***"each cell have black boundary"***.